# Adding file in Development/apps folder, not showing in apps menu

Tags: android, android-source, android-framework

I am trying to add my app in Android_source/Development/apps/ folder. I confirmed that my code is compiled, as if i add syntax error compiler stopped there.

*But the thing is that my app is not getting shown in apps menu*. should i add my app package somewhere else too.

Android.Mk file content(i copied these contents from Bluetooth App in packages/apps/Bluetooth)

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
        $(call all-java-files-under, src)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := Bluetooth_LE
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

#LOCAL_JNI_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libbluetooth_jni
LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES := javax.obex
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := com.android.vcard

LOCAL_REQUIRED_MODULES := libbluetooth_jni bluetooth.default

LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

Comment: Can you add your Android.mk file to the question?

Comment: done. It seems You are the only guy who is replying on android-source related questions. Thanks Yury for your efforts :)

Comment: Thanks! But I think you're not right - there are a number of people who try to answer in this tag. However, I just try to popularize android-source tag on StackOverflow, because I like it and for me it's easier to look for answers here then in different google-groups. However, you can still ask people in google groups related to Android platform development and I think they will try to help you! Some of them are very responsive and also have a lot of expertise in this sphere (some of them develop Android in Google).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you've forgot to include your package into the build. Put the name of your module (`Bluetooth_LE`) into appropriate build file (for instance, into `build/target/product/core.mk`) into section `PRODUCT_PACKAGES`.

Comment: ok. I will try and let you know if it works for me. may i know your mail ID. I have some doubts if you can help me out.

Comment: You can find how to write to me on my webpage the address of which is in my profile (I do not want to leave the address here because this is a very popular portal and after that I may receive a lot of spam).

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks. I added module name in core.mk , but dont have board with me. Will try out soon.

Comment: It doesn't add my app in APP menu even after adding it in core.mk

Comment: Maybe there are some different rules for development folder how to built. Do you application have a main activity?

Comment: Yes it has mainActivity. and other files. works good if installed directly.

Comment: Ok, maybe in the evening I'll check what I can do but I cannot promise ) If you do not find the answer you can ask this question in google groups.

Comment: Can you move your application to packages/apps and check the result?

Comment: I think it should be added in sdk.mk file in build folder. I am trying there too else will put it in Packages. will let you know

Comment: Tried everything, Added in packages with name in core.mk, sdk.mk. everyplace but no luc,

Comment: Then I do not think that the problem is in the build system. Is the package presented on an image? Do you see its executable?

Comment: it seems when i add moduleName in build/.../core.mk file new set of images are getting generated.
I can see statement like myApp.apk is installed in compilation logs.
Package.apk is getting generated in out/target/panda/obj folder.  But unfortunately my app is not getting shown in Apps Menu.

Comment: Where do you test your code? Do you test it on pandaboard? Why is it generated for panda?

Comment: Thanks Yuri, i think flashing has issue. I have another question, Basically Added an Java file in framework/base/core/java/ directory and a .cpp/jni file in base/jni folder, and i am not sure how can link these two files, so can call define native method in java which should be called in .cpp.